# When creating a new solution do I have to run the .\init.ps1 command again to prepare the container environment?

Tags: powershell, licensing, container

I am going through the Developer Fundamentals training for Sitecore 10 on the SiteCore website.  I created a solution prior to starting the training following my companies documentation.  When creating that solution, I ran  .\init.ps1, init2.bat, and docker-compose up -d.  As I am going through the training, [getting-started-template](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html), I ran this command `.\init.ps1 -InitEnv -LicenseXmlPath "<path to your license.xml file>" -AdminPassword "<your Sitecore administrator password>"` My powershell appears to be stuck at this part, Created a new local CA at "C:\Users\theRestOfMyPath".  I don't know if it is stuck because a certificate was already created the first time I ran the command for the other solution.  Do I just open a new Administrator Powershell window and run the rest of the commands?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to run the PowerShell in Admin mode and check the path of the license file. you need to add "license.xml". As shown in below screenshot.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Yamini

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to open the powershell in Admin mode.
Try to run the clean script from (clean.ps1) the folder first. It might be a folder deep (depending on how your folder is structured). This will remove everything from previous install. Then try again. I don't think your certificate is an issue here.

Do the following

Open Powershell in admin mode

1. Go to that directory using
2. cd [your directory path]/
3. .\init  [license path] (for me .\init “C:\sitecore\license\license.xml” )
4. docker-compose build solution
5. docker-compose build
6. docker-compose up -d

Don't forget to clean after you do the docker-compose down. Just run that clean.ps1 script from the folder.

There are few things you should know that pre-requisite for docker. Supported version of Windows are Windows 10 pro or Enterprise with version 20H2 is most stable. Also you must have WSL2.

Here is a link that might help.
http://mohammadhoque.com/?p=425

Hope this helps. Thank you.